# In R, how do I combine 2 nx2 arrays?

Tags: r

I'm just learning R for the first time. I've done something like this...

```
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- rnorm(50)
xcone <- cbind(x,y)
xctwo <- cbind(x+1,y+1)
```

I'd like to concatenate `xcone` and `xctwo` into a single variable, i.e.
`xcone = [(1,2),(3,4)]`, `xctwo = [(5,6),(7,8)]`, I'd like `output = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6),(7,8)]`

If I use:

```
output <- c(xcone,xctwo)
```

It seems to give me a list of all the numbers linearly? i.e.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: are you looking for `rbind(xcone,xtwo)` ?

Comment: Yes, perfect, thank you very much. My google fu failed me, the best I could find was an abind function which seems to be an additional library.

Comment: @Henry Do not be afraid of additional libraries. In fact, you *will* need them, you won’t get far without installing additional stuff in R. The base R is (intentionally) limited. Even core functionality is added by separate packages. (That said, in this case `rbind` is all that’s needed.)

Comment: I think you got result for `abind`, because you searched for array concatenation. Nx2 arrays are usually called matrices or data.frames; abind is designed for something with more dimensions

Comment: Thanks for the pointers guys. As you can see quite clearly I'm just getting set up in R for the first time ever :) Trying to come over from Python...!